# Sorting MySQL with several fields to choose from

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a portfolio which I would like to have listed in ASC sort order, according to several fields to choose from on top of the list. Without sorting the printout is perfect, but when activating the sort statement (line 35) I get the following error message:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in /home/domain/public_html/db_name/portfolio.php on
>   line 47

Can somebody please help and tell me what to do with this code? Many thanks for any advice:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../scripts/css/formate.css" />
</head>
<body>

<?php 
 // Connects to Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost","user","passw") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 ?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="?orderBy=ref_id">Order by Villa name   |</a></th>
        <th><a href="?orderBy=bedrooms">Order by no. of Beds   |</a></th>
        <th><a href="?orderBy=max_occupants">Order by Sleeps   </a></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
// sort table as selected
$orderBy = array('ref_id', 'bedrooms', 'max_occupants');
$order = 'ref_id';
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
    $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
}

// Read table ---> and sort it:

// $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM res_properties"); 

 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY '.$order"); 

 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 Print "<br><h3>Portfolio</h3 ><p> <br>";
 echo 'Listings as per: -       ';
 print date('r');
 print "\\n";
 Print "<br><p> <br>";

 Print "<table border cellpadding=3 >"; 
 Print "<tr align='center'><th width=130>Villa Name</th><th width=40>Beds</th><th width=40>Baths</th><th width=60>Sleeps</th><th width=200 >Property Website </th><th width=50 >Prop.ID</th></tr>"; 

   while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 

{ 

 Print "<tr align='center'><font face='arial' size='2' color='000000'>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info['ref_id'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<td>".$info['bedrooms'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info['bathrooms'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td>".$info['max_occupants'] . " </td>"; 
 Print "<td><a href=\"http://www.domain.com/properties/index.php/property/" . $info['slug'] . ".html\">Open website here</a></td>";
 Print "<td>".$info['id'] . "</td></tr> "; 

 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Always check the result of `mysql_query` and never assume that your queries will always succeed.

Answer (score 3):

I think its simply how your building your query.

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY '.$order");
```

to

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY " . $order);
```

If that doesn’t work add [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after execution of that statement and see what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY '$order'");
```

or

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY " . $order."'");
```

**NOTE 2** : Use of `mysql_*` function are [**deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) even it will generate [**`E_DEPRECATED`**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) warning in [**php5.5**](http://downloads.php.net/dsp/) so use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead if you want to learn pdo [here is good tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: Think your missing a ' after $order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?:

```
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY ' . $order . ' ASC');
```

In order to do ascending and descending sorting, you need to add another parameter to your link. Should it be `asc` or `desc` by default is your call, whatever makes more sense. In this case I made 0 for ascending and 1 for descending.

```
<a href="?orderBy=ref_id&sort=0">
```

The next thing you want to do is to add logic for sort handling:

```
$sortBy = array('asc', 'desc');
$sort = 0;
if (isset($_GET['sort']) && in_array($_GET['sort'], array_keys($sortBy))) {
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}
```

And the last thing to do is the change of `asc` to `desc` and vice versa when you click the link second time. If you put the code I provided (logic for sort handling) and the code for the `$order` handling above your navigation table (to make the variables accessible within the table), you can add a condition into the link:

```
<a href="?orderBy=ref_id&sort=<?php echo ($order == 'ref_id' ? !$sort : 0); ?>">
```

And you MySQL query will look something like this:

```
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY ' . $order . ' ' . $sortBy[$sort]);
```

Comment: Fantastic !
these both are  working fine:

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY " . $order); 
and this one:
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM db_row ORDER BY ' . $order . ' ASC'); 

Thank you so MUCH !

Now, the ideal solution was, if I could click on any of the field on top to sort ASC and click again to sort DESC. 

Would it be too much to ask for ? 
ANYWAY - THANKS TO ALL OF YOU for a professional advise !

Comment: Updated answer with sort handling. Glad to help!

Comment: @*Ranty** Thank you for all your fine work done, but I have to give up :-(
It works fine so far and sorts each fields ASC, if clicked, but I simply don't know where to put your code, to make it sort ASD / DESC.
PHP knows me, but I don't know PHP enough. Wish I would...Never mind and again: THANKS A LOT.